# yq to get values from key value pair

Tags: yaml, jq, yq

I have a simple values.yaml file which has below data:

```
images:
  tags:
    one: abc:v0.3-16-07
    two: xyz:ng-0.23.0
    pq: qaa:0df1e21e752b3d3.2020-04-27_1
```

Using

```
yq -r --yaml-output ".images.tags" values.yaml
```

I can get below output

```
one: abc:v0.3-16-07
two: xyz:ng-0.23.0
pq: qaa:0df1e21e752b3d3.2020-04-27_1
```

But how can i get the values from the above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to use `--yaml-output` flag, which tries to parse the output of the filter defined as a YAML entity. For getting the raw strings, use a filter in the JSON context itself

```
yq -r '.images.tags[]'
```

Comment: If only the values are needed then you could simplify to `yq -r '.images.tags[]' input`.

Comment: @luciole75w: I was actually thinking OP wanted the second part of values, so used the `to_entries` with `split()`. Made the edit now

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, Inian kind of posted an answer but there was a small change

`yq -r '.images.tags | to_entries[].value | split(":")[0]' values.yaml`